# @Resource is not working in JAR within WEB-INF/lib

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jndi

OK, it's simple: I'm injecting a JNDI Resource in a class that is under a jar in my WAR's WEB-INF/lib, using the @Resource annotation. It's not working. Why? Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: Using InitialContext.doLookup it works, though

Comment: Are you passing the same name to `@Resource` that you pass to Context.lookup?

Comment: yes, IntialContext.doLookup("java:global/test") works, @Resource(lookup="java:global/test") doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Just try to insert it through the same annotation with help of "Lookup" like this

> @Resource(lookup="JNDI_name")

Hope this can work because in my case it works.

Comment: Doesn't work. It only works if I annotate classes within the WAR, not classes in jars from WEB-INF/lib